# Difference Mb/s and mbps as a measure of data rate

Tags: digital-communications

["... Ka-band radio system flown to the moon (100 Mb/s)..."](https://www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet91/b91lutz.htm)

Mb/s is megabit pro second or megabyte pro second?

Can I write 100 mbps?

Mb/s and mbps, are different units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write 100Mb/s as 100mbps.

b = bits, B = bytes

Mb/s = Megabits per second.

MB/s = Megabytes per second.

**Mbps** (in some languages mbps) means megabits per second. Mb is used in reference to download and upload speeds. It takes 8 bits of data to equal 1 byte.

In EU area there are few other terms and abbreviations used for the same unit as can be seen in [IATE terminology bank](https://iate.europa.eu/entry/result/1592670/all).

**MBps** stands for megabytes per second. MB is used in reference to file size, or the amount of data transferred.

Answer (score 0):

M refers to mega which is just the number times 10^6. "bps" refers to bits per second which is equal to b/s.
If you use "B" instead of "b" which means Bytes, 8 bits = 1 Byte.

Answer (score -1):

1 Byte = 8 bits

100Mb/s = 800mbps

Comment: Of course, the translation is not necessarily this straightforward. With error correction, handshake overhead etc, the actual data rate is going to be somewhat lower. Depending on the protocol and external conditions, you might expect around 10 bits per byte.

Comment: [here](https://www.softperfect.com/contact/knowledgebase.php?article=10) I have read Mbps or  Mb/s is  megabit per second. I understood they determine the same unit. It is not clear now...

Comment: The answer should have MB/s with an uppercase B, though in practice you seem them mixed up quite a lot.